# Book Series identification, late 80s, early 90s

Tags: story-identification

I read a series of 5 novels that began with a space pirate kidnapping a woman from Earth, using her horribly, selling her or perhaps losing her to anothe pirate and her tale grew more awful... Each time you thought her plight could not get worse, the author twisted it more. The protagonist also went through many trials by the end of the series. The protagonist's name was Nick and I don't recall her name. She did eventually triumph.

Anyone know? TIA if so!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be *[The Gap Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gap_Cycle)* by Stephen Donaldson. Summary of the first book:

> On her first mission, Morn Hyland, an ensign in the United Mining Companies Police (UMCP), discovers that she suffers a rare psychosis called "gap sickness." Whenever her ship comes out of an FTL jump through "the Gap," she falls into a trance and feels compelled to activate any self-destruct or other sabotage within her reach. The first time her ship jumps, she destroys the police ship, killing the entire crew, including her own family. She survives the wreck only because a **vicious pirate named Angus Thermopylae** finds her when he boards looking for salvage. In order to neutralize her gap sickness and exploit her for his own ends, Angus places a "zone implant" in her brain -- a remotely controlled electrode which allows Angus to control Morn's every feeling and action. Angus uses the zone implant to repeatedly rape and abuse her. Misuse of a zone implant is a capital crime, Angus risks execution if he is discovered, but hopes the zone implant itself will prevent Morn from exposing him. When they arrive at Com-Mine, the nearest space station, Morn makes contact with **another pirate — Nick Succorso**, captain and owner of the ship Captain's Fancy, who she sees as a potential rescuer. Morn and Nick collude to frame Angus for stealing station supplies. However, before he is arrested, Angus asks Morn to smuggle the implant's remote control off the station. During her captivity, Morn has become addicted to the artificial stimuli only the implant can provide; because of her addiction, she is unable to turn down Angus' offer. Rather than turn herself in to the police for treatment, she conceals the existence of her implant. With her own controls in her possession, Morn is effectively a superwoman and is able to disregard fear, pain, or fatigue; however, by continuing to use the zone implant on herself, she, like Angus, breaks the law against unauthorized use. Morn joins Nick's pirate crew to escape from police oversight, even concealing her implant from Nick himself. Because she left no evidence of Angus' real crimes, he is imprisoned for the theft of which he was framed, but is not executed for what he did to Morn. Although the series has at least one chapter each from over a dozen narrators, Morn, Angus, and their son Davies are main protagonists of the entire series.

One of the covers:
[image: Book cover]

Comment: Author appeal...?

Comment: Sweet! Thanks again! Re-buying to re-read :)